# Auto-resolving a hostname in WCF Metadata Publishing

Tags: wcf, url, metadata

I am running a self-hosted WCF service.  In the service configuration, I am using **localhost** in my BaseAddresses that I hook my endpoints to.  When trying to connect to an endpoint using the WCF test client, I have no problem connecting to the endpoint and getting the metadata using the machine's name.  The problem that I run into is that the client that is generated from metadata uses localhost in the endpoint URLs it wants to connect to.  I'm assuming that this is because **localhost** is the endpoint URL published by metadata.  As a result, any calls to the methods on the service will fail since **localhost** on the calling machine isn't running the service.

What I would like to figure out is if it is possible for the service metadata to publish the proper URL to a client depending on the client who is calling it.  For example, if I was requesting the service metadata from a machine on the same network as the server the endpoint should be **net.tcp://MYSERVER:1234/MyEndpoint**.  If I was requesting it from a machine outside the network, the URL should be **net.tcp://MYSERVER.mydomain.com:1234/MyEndpoint**.  And obviously if the client was on the same machine, THEN the URL could be **net.tcp://localhost:1234/MyEndpoint**.

Is this just a flaw in the default IMetadataExchange contract?  Is there some reason the metadata needs to publish the information in a non-contextual way?  Is there another way I should be configuring my BaseAddresses in order to get the functionality I want?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What .NET version are you using? If you're using .NET 4.0, add the UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior to your service host:

```
UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior urh = 
    new UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior();
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(urh);
```

Obviously, this needs to be done prior to opening the service host.

If you're using .NET 3.5, there's a hotfix that adds this behavior:  support.microsoft.com/kb/971842.